# Cannot build artifact 'ProjectName:war exploded'

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I was working with a Java project in the `IntelliJ` platform and started over after reinstalling the Mac OS again. The project structure looks slightly weird now with `BitCoinWalletApp[1] and BitCoinWalletApp[2]`,

[image]

When I run with the `Tomcat 8`, I get the following error,

```
Error:Cannot build artifact 'BitcoinWalletApp (2):war exploded' because it is included into a circular dependency (artifact 'BitcoinWalletApp (2):war exploded', artifact 'BitcoinWalletApp (1):war exploded')
```

Whats the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: Intellij IDEA oddly created submodules in your java and resources folders. You can try to remove all the *.iml files and import your project again.

Comment: Circular dependencies refer to the fact that you use A in B and B in A (hence the circle). You mught want to check your pom.

Comment: The problem is solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out this happened because the project has more than one pom.xml file which intelliJ detected as another source of valid pom.xml, in this case its pom.xml.back, to fix it, delete the backup version of your pom.xml