# IntelliJ Idea created extra .iml files when it's not supposed to

Tags: intellij-idea, circular-dependency

I have this exact same problem as the one in this SO: [Cannot build artifact 'ProjectName:war exploded'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541205/cannot-build-artifact-projectnamewar-exploded), but when I tried to remove the .iml files and reimport maven project again, the 2 .iml files show up again, these affected the artifacts and other project settings that made me unable to run the project

[image]
[image: example artifacts on project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out this happened because the project has
`pom.xml.versionsBackup` file which intelliJ detected as another source of valid pom.xml, I deleted the backup and everything working normally now

Answer (score 0):

Use File | New | Project from [Existing Sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#create-from-sources) action and select to delete the existing configuration.